# Error al ingresar un numero celular en mi base de datos mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, xampp, estructuras-de-datos

mi problema es sobre un taller que tengo que hacer, y ya cree la base de datos con los siguientes parametros

```
create table Universidad
->     (
->     id_estudiante int unsigned not null auto_increment,
->     Nombre varchar(10),
->     Apellido varchar(10),
->     Programa varchar(10),
->     Edad int(2),
->     Celular int(10),
->     primary key (id_estudiante)
->      );
```

Entonces al momento de ingresar un valor en la variable de **Celular** no se queda el numero sino que se pone un numero todo random y he intentado buscar pero no se como comenzar, entonces quisiera saber como podria solucionarlo, cabe recalcar que una de las preguntas del tutor es:

> Observe el campo Celular y verifique si la información almacenada en ese campo fue la que
> realmente ingresaste. Si su respuesta es NO, indique por qué sucedió esto y cuál sería tu
> solución para este inconveniente.
> Imagenes de lo ingresado y valores de la tabla

```
insert into universidad (Nombre, Apellido, Programa, Edad, Celular) value
-> ("JUAN GABRIEL", "CARVAJAL VEGA", "INGENIERIA DE SOFTWARE", 39, 3002154993),
-> ("ANDRES FEDERICO", "SALDARRIAGA CONDE", "INGENIERIA ELECTRICA", 25, 3201234567),
-> ("SERGIO ALEXANDER", "RODRIGUEZ HURTADO", "INGENIERIA DE ALIMENTOS", 32, 3151234567),
-> ("GUSTAVO EDUARDO", "SANCHEZ OVIEDO", "INGENIERIA DE SOFTWARE", 21, 3101234567),
-> ("ALVARO JOSE", "PAREDES PALENCIA", "INGENIERIA ELECTRICA", 35, 3181234567);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero ayudas y les agradeceria si tienen alguna pagina que expliquen mejor, Gracias a todos :D

Comment: te he puesto la solución dime si te funciona

Comment: A ver, guardar un número de teléfono en un campo numérico es una mala idea, lo miren por donde lo miren. Lo mismo aplica para el número de la seguridad social, o cualquier número identificativo (pasaporte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema estaba en que las longitudes de los campos era insuficiente y en el caso de celular el tipo `int` alcanza como mucho `2147483647` y tu lo superas por eso te lo puse tipo `varchar(11)` para que se guarde correctamente

```
create table Universidad(
    id_estudiante int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    Nombre varchar(25),
    Apellido varchar(25),
    Programa varchar(25),
    Edad int(2),
    Celular varchar(11),
    primary key (id_estudiante)
);

insert into Universidad (Nombre, Apellido, Programa, Edad, Celular) value
("JUAN GABRIEL", "CARVAJAL VEGA", "INGENIERIA DE SOFTWARE", 39, 3002154993),
("ANDRES FEDERICO", "SALDARRIAGA CONDE", "INGENIERIA ELECTRICA", 25, 3201234567),
("SERGIO ALEXANDER", "RODRIGUEZ HURTADO", "INGENIERIA DE ALIMENTOS", 32, 3151234567),
("GUSTAVO EDUARDO", "SANCHEZ OVIEDO", "INGENIERIA DE SOFTWARE", 21, 3101234567),
("ALVARO JOSE", "PAREDES PALENCIA", "INGENIERIA ELECTRICA", 35, 3181234567);
```

**Te dejo un enlace con el funcionamiento :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/102

Comment: muchas gracias, la verdad despues de un rato un compa me dijo que era mejor ponerlo en bigint, y la verdad no me habia acordado del limite del int, hasta estaba por cambiarlo a varchar pero ya entendí muchisimas gracias :D

Comment: de nada bro : )

Answer (score -1):

puedes intentar cambiando el valor que esta recibiendo en la columna de celular por solamente "int" de esta forma:

```
create table Universidad(
    id_estudiante int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    Nombre varchar(25),
    Apellido varchar(25),
    Programa varchar(25),
    Edad int(2),
    Celular int,
    primary key (id_estudiante)
);
```

Comment: eso no funciona ya lo intente yo